# Group SQL results with similar values - (not exact values)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table `books` such as the below.

| id | title | author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Karen's Diary | Karen A |
| 2 | Karens Diary | Karen B |
| 3 | Sharon's Diary | Sharon C |
| 4 | Sharon's Diary <3 | Sharon D |
| 5 | Sharons Diary! | Sharon D |

My SQL;

`SELECT title, COUNT(id) AS count FROM books GROUP BY title`

Result:

| title | count |
| --- | --- |
| Karen's Diary | 1 |
| Karens Diary | 1 |
| Sharon's Diary | 1 |
| Sharon's Diary <3 | 1 |
| Sharons Diary! | 1 |

I'm trying to get the results to recognise similar titles that may be spelt differently or with/without punctuation. Is this possible with a simple function? GROUP BY only appears to match exact cases. I've looked in to other solutions like left() or regexp_replace() but there are just too many variables to account for and make it complicated.

Ideal result:

| title | count |
| --- | --- |
| Karen's Diary | 2 |
| Sharon's Diary | 3 |

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you can use nested REPLACE functions, if you want to do simple text processing (like removing single quotes, exclamation marks, and angle brackets). 
And if your text has complex patterns or much more special characters, and also you're comfortable with regular expressions, then REGEXP_REPLACE is a robust and flexible option worth considering. 

I don't think there are other options available.

Comment: you should start by defining "similar value" then work from it. the common approach would be using levenshtein distance. unfortunately, mysql does not support levenshtein distance out of the box afaik. you need an indexer not dbms.

Comment: Well, you provided very few sample data and you are very vague about your reuqirements. Given your sample rows, we can just use `LEFT` to get the desired result: `SELECT MIN(title) AS title, COUNT(id) AS count FROM books GROUP BY LEFT(title,5);` See https://dbfiddle.uk/YRNJdQeK. I guess your real situation is more complex. So you will need to explain your real use case.

Comment: This is called fuzzy matching and it is a complex area. The main problem is how to avoid false matches while make sure you match everything ypu can. Levenshtein distance is indeed a common technique to detect misspellings, but it is blind - treats all differences the same. It is usually combined with removal of certain characters (e.g. punctuation) and giving differences in certain characters a higher significance. You also need to define somehow that out of the similar values which one is the "master", the ine one you compare all other results to. This is even more difficult.

Comment: You could also try to use `SOUNDEX`, see the result with your sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/z3VtWjK2 and the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex